# .js getting bypassed and going to .ejs Node.js Express Router

Tags: node.js, express, router

Trying to query MySql (RDS) from AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Problem started when I started using Express and Router.

I guess it is going straight to .ejs file and not via .js file. Hence the query is not executed and the corresponding variable data not present.

**How do I tell my router (Express) to use (execute) .js file and then to .ejs file?**

My routes.js looks like this

```
const express = require('express');
const router = new express.Router();
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index');
});

router.get('/testtable', (req, res) => {
    res.render('testtable');
  });

module.exports = router;
```

My routes folder has a testtable.js file

```
exports.list = function(req, res){
    req.getConnection(function(err,connection){   
        var query = connection.query('SELECT * FROM eduguy.mymailer',function(err,rows){
          if(err)
            console.log("Error Selecting------------xxxxx : %s ",err );

          res.render('testtable',{page_title:"Test Table",data:rows});
        });
    });
  };
```

And my views folder has testtable.ejs like this.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Elastic Beanstalk</title>
  </head>  
 <body>
    <table border="1" cellpadding="7" cellspacing="7" align="center">
      <caption>Email Lists</caption>
      <tr>
        <th width="50px"> <input type="checkbox" name="all" value="all" onclick="for(c in document.getElementsByName('row')) document.getElementsByName('row').item(c).checked = this.checked"> </th>
        <th width="50px">No</th>
        <th>Field 1</th>
        <th>Field 2</th>
        <th>Field 3</th>
      </tr>
      <% if(data.length){ 
        for(var i = 0;i < data.length;i++) { %>
      <tr>
        <td> <input type="checkbox" name="row" value="<%=data[i].email%>"></td>
        <td><%=(i+1)%></td>
        <td><%=data[i].name%></td>
        <td><%=data[i].email%></td>
        <td><%=data[i].column1%></td>
      </tr>
      <% }
      }else{ %>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">No user</td>
      </tr>
    <% } %>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```